# Solve using Chebyshev's Sum Inequality

Tags: inequality

To show:
$$ \left(\frac1n \sum x_i^4 \right)\left(\frac1n \sum x_i^2 \right) \geqslant \left(\frac1n\sum x_i^3\right)^2 $$

I am new to stack exchange and dont know how to insert equations. I was trying to solve the inequation in the url above, using Chebyshev sum inequality.

I tried using $A_i- > X_i$ and Bi -> Xi2. But no use.
Also tried Ai,Bi-> Xi and Ai,Bi->Xi2, and tried multiplying the inequalities. No use either. Please help me.

Comment: I have tried to help you with the formatting.  Please check by clicking "edit" in grey below the question to see how its done.  You may be able to do similar for the rest of the question - remember to enclose the formula in dollar signs, and subscripts by underscores, rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is true by C-S:
$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^4\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\geq\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^3\right)^2.$$

If you want Chebyshov, so after expanding it's enough to prove that:
$$x_i^4x_j^2+x_i^2x_j^4\geq2x_i^3x_j^3$$ or
$$x_i^2+x_j^2\geq2x_ix_j,$$ which follows from Chebyshov:
$$(x_i+x_j)(x_i+x_j)\geq2(x_ix_j+x_jx_i),$$ but by C-S it's a bit of better, I think.